# what is this resource missing eror in GWt+Maven svn project

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, gwt

i have a Maven+GWt+Svn project in that i am Client Bundle interface to include images when i am including path of the image using @source annotation it is giving me resource missing error...image is available at the specified path.. m2e connector also i have installed in my eclipse... any suggestion
this is my code

```
public interface ValueBundleResources extends ClientBundle {
    public static final ValueBundleResourcesINSTANCE =  GWT.create(ValueBundleResources.class);

    @Source("com/value/frontend/public/img/icon/actions/delete.gif")
    public ImageResource deleteIcon();

    @Source("com/value/frontend/public/img/icon/actions/clean.png")
    public ImageResource cleanIcon();
}
```

Comment: **What** exactly is showing an error? It wouldn't surprise me that Eclipse gives you a warning or error; but does the build with Maven work or fail?

Comment: maven build is failed...

Comment: Given that you path is "absolute" (relative to the classpath), try prefixing it with `/`: `@Source("/com/value/frontend/public/img/icon/actions/delete.gif")`. Note that you can also use relative paths (including ones that use `../`) but keep in mind that they are evaluated as resource paths in the classpath, not file paths in the filesystem.